Unable to open config database
[root@pc-1460 ~]# useradd Romain
[sss_cache] [confdb_init] (0x0010): Unable to open config database [/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb]
Could not open available domains
[sss_cache] [confdb_init] (0x0010): Unable to open config database [/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb]

Any idae why this is in error and how to resolve it?
Running on AlmaLinux 8.8
And also
su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Too many open files in system


If the noted file is there, and the permissions are correct, the former is most probably a result of the latter.
